# How to remove array elements where element's fields are NULL

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
array = [[1555,100],[nil,95],[1774,nil],[1889,255]]
```

What would be the best way to remove the 2nd and 3rd elements from array since they have `NULL` fields?

Expected output :

```
array = [[1555,100],[1889,255]]
```

Comment: Can you paste the expected output for above example?

Comment: @Ragnar921 : You mean `nil`, not `NULL`. Ruby does not have a `NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

```
arr = [[1555,100],[nil,95],[1774,nil],[1889,255]]
```

```
arr.reject { |a,b| (a && b).nil? }
  #=> [[1555, 100], [1889, 255]]
```

Answer (score 4):

And yet another option:

```
array.reject { |a| a.any?(&:nil?) }
```

It is very similar to Cary Swoveland's answer, but will work with arrays of any length and will remove `[false, nil]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.compact` to remove `nil` elements from array of arrays

```
array.map(&:compact)

# array = [[1555,100], [95], [1774], [1889, 255]]
```

**Edit**

Use `.reject!` to remove sub arrays containing `nil` elements.

```
array.reject! { |e| e.any? nil }

# array = [[1555,100], [1889,255]]
```

Comment: I want the whole array element gone if it includes a `NULL`

Comment: I have edit the answer.